# Commonalities & Differences between these Scans for Knee Joint?

Tags: medical-imaging, orthopedics, knee

**Commonalities & Differences between these Scans for Knee Joint?**

- MRI Scan Knee Joint
- MRI Scan Knee Arthrography
- MRI Scan Knee Joint Contrast (Fasting Reqd)
- MRI Scan Knee with Cartilage Mapping

(This is as listed in Radio Imaging Lab's options and similar but different words are being used online from whatever I read. More confused and less clear).

**Direction on inquiry:**

- Are some of them Super Sets of other on the list?
- What can each of them help show/ uncover from the knee structures & tissues and/or not?
- When would one be preferred over another and when might one escalate to the "greater/ finer" one of them?

**Maybe someone can share some highlights**

**+**

**Link me to a good comparative article or study that can shed light on the above?**

PS: My googling has not been able to give much clarity on the above

---

UPDATE:

More reading and more confusion between these terms and wondering which are same or different.

- Arthrography | Arthrogram | Arthro-Scopy | Angiography |

Some articles mention MR with Athrogram as with Contrast dye injection

https://alliance-mri.com/2018/07/arthrogram-vs-mri-what-are-the-key-differences/

https://mrimaster.com/PLAN%20MRA%20LEGS.html

https://www.omegapds.com/mri-vs-mra-how-to-know-which-imaging-test-is-best-for-you/

https://www.cms.gov/medicare-coverage-database/(S(mjf4pgrpk51jog45znsawg55))/details/ncd-details.aspx?NCDId=177&NCAId=246&NcaName=Magnetic+Resonance+Imaging+(MRI)&bc=AEAAAAAAEAgA

http://mri-q.com/2d-vs-3d-mra.html

Comment: Could you please clarify where these things come from and why you're asking? It's all rather abrupt and without background.

Comment: I said so already. It’s from a radio lab list and I’m trying understand how they work. Curious how far the tech is able to map different structures.

Comment: @CareyGregory - Added some links from going through around 40 or 50 links. Google doesnt help clarify.